# php multiple if's but not related

Tags: php, if-statement

I have a WP site but this is a PHP question, I have the following code:

```
f(!empty($c_dates1_new)) { ?>
    <p class="text">Dates: From <?php echo $c_dates1_new; ?> to <?php echo $c_datee1_new; ?></p>
   <?php } if(!empty($c_dates2_new)) { ?>
    <p class="text">Dates 2: From <?php echo $c_dates2_new; ?> to <?php echo $c_datee2_new; ?></p> 
   <?php } if(!empty($c_dates3_new)) { ?>
    <p class="text">Dates 3: From <?php echo $c_dates3_new; ?> to <?php echo $c_datee3_new; ?></p>
   <?php } if(!empty($c_dates4_new)) { ?>
    <p class="text">Dates 4: From <?php echo $c_dates4_new; ?> to <?php echo $c_datee4_new; ?></p>
   <?php }
```

Now this only shows the content from $c_dates_1 where it should display the content from all of them.

I cannot workout what I need to put between them e.g. it's not an else, it's not an OR and it's not an AND as they are all separate checks, not related to each other.

any input is appreciated

Comment: are you sure that the variables $c_dates2_new to $c_dates4_new does have values? Try to type if(true) just for testing...

Comment: Your if statement looks good, are you sure the variables are not empty? Use `print_r` to print them

Comment: Why don't you just for a second remove those if statements and see if actually something gets printed. if nothing prints then they are empty.

Comment: [**Your code works completely fine - your error must be elsewhere**](http://codepad.org/mBNF4yAD). What does `var_dump($c_dates1_new, $c_dates2_new, $c_dates3_new, $c_dates4_new)` reveal?

Comment: fixed it, had a tiny error in an if else before which meant it was calling the data from the first box and not the 2, 3rd and 4th.